# When creating an AWS Auto-Scaling Launch Configuration & using spot instances - How can I set a maximum price based on unit type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling, spot-instances

I regularly am seeing the following througout various AWS documentation:

> If you set TargetCapacityUnitType to vcpu or memory-mib , the price
> protection threshold is applied based on the per-vCPU or per-memory
> price instead of the per-instance price.

[image]

Most importantly, I see it on the [create-launch-template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-launch-template.html) documentation.

I would like to create a launch configuration for an auto-scaling group that will use a variety of instance types based on their [attribute-based selection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/create-asg-instance-type-requirements.html).

This will of course, allow me to use a number of various instance types - making my spot request more eligible for being fulfilled and have less interruptions.

I've found that I'm able to set a maximum price defined as "Per instance/hour" - but if I'm using a variety of instances which have a slew of different pricing, this of course breaks down.

For this reason - The [request-spot-fleet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/request-spot-fleet.html) API call has a means of setting a `TargetCapacityUnitType` so that you're able to define a maximum price based on vCPU or memory instead.

It seems like all the pieces are here - and the aforementioned 'Note' is even on the `create-launch-template` documentation; but I cannot find where to actually define `TargetCapacityUnitType` in my Launch Configuration.

When creating an AWS Auto-Scaling Launch Configuration & using spot instances - How can I set a maximum price based on unit type? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a launch template with your AMI and then use the launch template to create the group. You don't use a launch configuration at all.

All properties you specify for attribute-based instance type selection are part of a mixed instances policy, which is part of the create-auto-scaling-group call.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).